# AppEngine Pipeline executed twice

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, pipeline, webapp2

When I am running a Pipeline, it gets executed twice. I don't understand where is the duplication of calls coming from. Any ideas?

Here is the pipeline code:

```
class RetryFunction(webapp2.RedirectHandler):
  def get(self):
    logging.debug("in retryFunction")
    pipeline = PipelineFanout()
    pipeline.start()
    path = pipeline.base_path + "/status?root=" + pipeline.pipeline_id
    self.redirect(path)
```

Here is the execution log, where you can see the RetryFunction being run twice, even though I call it only once by a URL route from my browser:

```
2014-04-27 11:43:41.487 /retryFunction 302 1887ms 0kb instance=0 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36 module=backend-pipeline version=1
 D 2014-04-27 11:43:41.335 in retryFunction
 I 2014-04-27 11:43:41.483 Saved; key: __appstats__:021300, part: 238 bytes, full: 25521 bytes, overhead: 0.002 + 0.004; link: http://backend-pipeline.myapp.appspot.
2014-04-27 11:43:41.445 /retryFunction 302 1159ms     0kb instance=0 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like     Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36 module=backend-pipeline version=1
 D 2014-04-27 11:43:41.339 in retryFunction
```

EDIT - This seems to happen only when I purged the queue before launching a new run. I wonder if there isn't something left in the cache that causes the job to be called twice the next time...

EDIT2 - The same pipeline gets executed twice when it didn't complete properly, and after a fix and redeployment I try to run it again, then it gets executed twice.

EDIT3 - Here is another example of logs where we see the original service call. I call it once, it gets executed twice:

```
2014-05-12 08:55:04.198 /myservice 302 2033ms 0kb instance=0 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36 module=backend-pipeline version=1
 D 2014-05-12 08:55:04.007 Starting new PipelineFanout
 D 2014-05-12 08:55:04.196 After Starting new pipeline.start() Pipeline. Pipeline id: 73769b67097a475e82ba28ff27b549f5

2014-05-12 08:55:04.192 **/myservice** 302 1344ms 0kb instance=0 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36 module=backend-pipeline version=1
 D 2014-05-12 08:55:04.002 Starting new PipelineFanout
 D 2014-05-12 08:55:04.185 After Starting new pipeline.start() Pipeline. Pipeline id: 11d74391f39145bdbb96915aef319763
 I 2014-05-12 08:55:04.189 Saved; key: __appstats__:004000, part: 172 bytes, full: 25464 bytes, overhead: 0.002 + 0.004; link: http://backend-pipeline.myapp.appspot.
```

EDIT4 - Strangely enough, when I execute the pipelines on a separate queue (not the default one), this problem seems to go away.

Comment: Here is the behavior I think is happening:
When a pipeline is being forced shutdown for any reason, sometimes the finalized() function is not called. In the meantime, if you call this pipeline for a new execution, the pipeline will duplicate the call and the pipeline will be executed twice with a few ms of delay. Once for the new pipeline, once for the cached pipeline. If you change the queue of execution for this pipeline, the problem will stop.